# How to copy file in clipboard buffer when running ssh on linux?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, console

For example I am Using Mac and ssh'ed to Linux server(Ubuntu, no X-session) and need to transfer SSL certificate from one server to another (also Linux console, Ubuntu, no X-session), how would I copy certificate with clipboard, is it possible?

I know how to copy using cat and mouse :) For example cert is not printable in console or too big

Comment: If it's just an SSL certificate in printable format I would use the mouse, otherwise @tjt263's answer is nice. You really need to give more context (are you on a Linux console or X session, with what terminal, using ssh to a second Linux and do you want to copy to a third Linux also accessed by ssh from the first Linux, or is there any Windows mixed up in there). This is needed because frankly doing a copy-n-paste is so simple that the main problem we have is understanding what your difficulty is . . .

Comment: @Law29 updated, yes it's bash console

Comment: I asked if you were on a Linux console or in an X session, I should probably have asked "do you have a mouse-pointer-thing that moves around on your screen when you move your physical mouse?" and "Does your mouse have a middle button?" and "Are you on a Windows PC using putty or are you really using Linux to type?". I'll try to make an answer out of all this.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63295405/1020550) will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy a file from one server to another I would usually use `scp`. It is a program to copy files over ssh. You can either scp the file from the first Ubuntu to your Mac and then from your Mac to the second Ubuntu, or if there are no firewalls and such you can scp directly from the first Ubuntu to the second. The syntax is `scp localpathsrc login@server:remotepathdst` or `scp login@server:remotepathsrc localpathdst` (with the newest scp I think you can also use scp login1@server1:path1src login2@server2:path2dst, but you won't have that on your Mac nor on Ubuntu 12.04). On Ubuntu you should have scp, it comes in the package openssh-client, but maybe you only have openssh-server installed. On Mac, I'm afraid I don't know...

Without installing anything at all you should also be able to do from a terminal on your Mac

```
ssh login1@server1 "cat path" | ssh login2@server2 "cat > path2"
```

but I don't remember if that works when you have to type passwords.

Answer (score 3):

### X Toolkit

I think you just want some tools from the standard X Toolkit:
`xclipboard`; `xclip`; `xcutsel`; `xclip-copyfile`; `xclip-cutfile`; `xclip-pastefile`; etc..

---

```
NAME
   xclip-copyfile, xclip-cutfile, xclip-pastefile

   - copy and move files via the X clipboard.

SYNOPSIS
   xclip-copyfile  [-p] FILES...

   xclip-cutfile   [-p] FILES...

   xclip-pastefile

DESCRIPTION
   xclip-copyfile  copies files into the X clipboard, recursing into directories.

   xclip-cutfile   copies the files, but also deletes them afterwards.

   -p              preserve path formation

   xclip-pastefile pastes the files out of the clipboard

EXAMPLES
   Copying a file to a remote host

   [maggie.lkpg.cendio.se ~]$ echo "A file created on ${HOSTNAME}" > file1
   [maggie.lkpg.cendio.se ~]$ xclip-copyfile file1
   [sofie.homeip.net ~/doc]$ xclip-pastefile
   file1
   [sofie.homeip.net ~/doc]$ cat file1
   A file created on maggie.lkpg.cendio.se

   Copying an entire tree structure

   [sofie.homeip.net ~]$ xclip-copyfile doc
   [maggie.lkpg.cendio.se ~/tmp]$ xclip-pastefile
   doc/
   doc/letter-mom-april.txt
   doc/file1
   doc/letter-dad-march.txt

   Copying files with preserved path information

   [maggie.lkpg.cendio.se ~]$ xclip-copyfile -p /etc/sysconfig/grub
   tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
   [sofie.homeip.net ~/tmp]$ xclip-pastefile
   etc/sysconfig/grub
   [sofie.homeip.net ~/tmp]$ ls etc/sysconfig/grub
   etc/sysconfig/grub

   Moving files

   [sofie.homeip.net ~]$ ls letter-brother-may.txt
   letter-brother-may.txt
   [sofie.homeip.net ~]$ xclip-cutfile letter-brother-may.txt
   [sofie.homeip.net ~]$ ls letter-brother-may.txt
   ls: cannot access letter-brother-may.txt: No such file or directory
   [sofie.homeip.net ~]$ cd doc
   [sofie.homeip.net ~/doc]$ xclip-pastefile
   letter-brother-may.txt

AUTHORS
   This manual page was written by Maximilian Gass for the Debian project. 
   It may be used for everything else, of course.
```

Comment: thanks, but how to get these tools installed on ubuntu?

Comment: They should be there already. Search with `apt-cache search`. Install with `apt-get install`. These are very common commands, you will need to get acquainted with them.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot seriously believe that you are using a Linux console... do you have a mouse? If so:

- use the command `cat myfile` to show the whole file on your terminal. Make the terminal bigger if necessary to show the whole file. If it's just a certificate it shouldn't be a problem.
- Place the mouse pointer at the beginning of the file shown in your terminal.
- Hold down the left button
- Move the mouse to the other end of the file so that it is all highlighted
- Release the mouse button. The file's contents should stay highlighted. This copies the highlighted text to the X clipboard (which is a different one than the one you use when you do Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V in some applications).
- Access your other server.
- Open a file editor (if you use `vi` put it in insert mode)
- Press the mouse middle button to paste the contents.

If you're not using a mouse, then you may not have X libraries installed. Use `scp` instead of the X clipboard.

This is supposing you are actually logged on a X session. Given the vagueness of your question you might be on a Windows PC and using putty to access the two linux servers. If so, use the right button to paste.

Comment: I wouldn't ask how to copy with X session, it's obvious.

Comment: So... what are you asking? I *still* don't know if you are working on a Windows machine with putty or on a Linux machine. If your question is *how to insert a file into the clipboard without having to output it to the terminal and select the contents with the mouse*, then @tjt263 has answered. We can't tell you how to install those programs since they differ according to the Linux distribution, and you haven't told us what that is (or those are). BTW it would be interesting to know why you cannot use *scp*.

Comment: Finally I got what you meant, sorry for confusing. I am using Mac and ssh to Linux Ubuntu 12.04. I have no 'xclipboard' or `scp` on Mac neither Ubuntu, how would I get it?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: And so I wrote a new answer to your updated question; it seems it worked for you, cool!